# How to document a namespace using yuidoc?

Tags: javascript, yuidoc

[YUIDoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/) doesn't seem to be generating any documentation for my namespace.  This project uses the [Revealing Module](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/) design pattern

```
/*
 * Example namespace.
 *
 * @namespace MY_NAMESPACE
 */
var MY_NAMESPACE = (function() {
  /**
   * @property privateProperty1
   * @type {Number}
   * @private
   */
  var privateProperty1 = 1;

  /**
   * Logs the method name to the console.
   * @method privateMethod1
   * @private
   */
  var privateMethod1 = function() {
    console.log('In privateMethod1');
  };

  return {
    /**
     * @property publicProperty1
     * @type {Number}
     */
    publicProperty1: 2,

    /**
     * Logs a simple message to the console.
     *
     * @method publicMethod1
     * @param {String} aString A string to log. 
     */
    publicMethod1: function(aString) {
      console.log('In publicMethod1 and was passed: ' + aString);
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@namespace` needs to contains a `@class` if you want to use `@namespace` as follows, but you may want to use a `@class` instead of `@namespace`.

```
/**
* Example namespace.
* @namespace MY_NAMESPACE
*/

/**
* Example class.
* @class MyClass
*/
```